# Two equal acronym - What should I do?

Tags: acronyms

I'm using the `acronym` package.

I have in two chapters the acronym MAC one time for "Media Access Control" and in the second chapter as "Message Authentication Code".

How can I use both MACs?

Is a other package better?

Comment: Maybe the answer to this question will answer yours too: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42214/managing-acronyms-with-a-macro-that-preserves-the-full-name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You definitely should use different acronyms/abbreviations for the two. Otherwise, it wouldn't be possible to distinguish between the two.

You could typeset one in small caps (`\textsc{}`) and one in a monospaced typeface (`\texttt{}`) but it's not ideal.

Another solution is using `\textsc{mac}` for media access control and `\textsc{ma}u\textsc{c}` for message authentication code.

BTW, your problem isn't that uncommon. For example, consider the abbreviation `CSP`. I've found the following different usages:

- Communicating Sequential Process;
- Constraint Satisfaction Problem;
- Constant Sign Partition;
- [192 more abbreviations](http://www.acronymfinder.com/CSP.html) omitted

Comment: For small caps, use `\textsc{mac}`, not `\textsc{MAC}`. The latter looks just like `MAC`.